# Spring security oauth2login redirect gives CORS error

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

Is it normal that a keycloak oauth2 provider should give cors error when app redirects (302) to auth endpoint?
Do I need to ask the provider to add access control allow origin ‘*’ to auth response?

We’re upgrading to spring security 6 spring boot 3, our previous spring security implementation had custom code to send unauthorised (401) with x-auth-location header for code secured content and this flow passed the CORS preflight check.

Comment: Allowing `*` as origin on Keycloak seems a bad idea for security. If your frontend knows how to handle it properly already, you can still configure your Spring 6 app to return 401 for unauthorized requests. Otherwise, if your frontend is a SPA, you might consider changing Spring response status from `302` to something in the `2xx` so that app itself handles the redirection by setting the `window.location.href`. This is [something I do frequently](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).